# Can't install win10 on new sshd

Tags: usb, windows-10, installation

I have new seagate sshd,
I have created bootable  USB drive,
After I boot into the windows installation There is no drive or patition to choose to install on them,
But when I click to browse for driver I can see there is this drive and windows has mouted it.

(I have downloaded latest windows image from Microsoft's site)
I tried it several times but without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cloned another hdd with windows to sshd and after that I swaped the main hdd with sshd

Only after this I was able to install windows normally into sshd.

Still I don't know what caused this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found on certain PC models that I have been unable to install Windows from a USB flash drive. In each of those situations, however, I was able to successfully install Windows from a burnt DVD. I haven't bothered to investigate, but if I had to guess, I would say it has something to do either UEFI or possibly SSD's in need of a firmware update (some of them are rather unreliable when running the original factory firmware).